# Sql Insert with dynamic values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using following query on postgres database:

```
insert into user_settings (google_access_token, google_refresh_token) 
   select 'google_access_token', 'google_refresh_token' from user 
   where id = user_id
```

table user_settings has a field `user_id` which corresponds to field named `id` in user table. but this gives the error:

```
column "user_id" does not exist 
Hint: There is a column named "user_id" in table "user_settings", 
but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please describe the actual problem and give some example of what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are taking a column in user_settings and inserting into that table with condition.
I think you have to use update statement because your condition is

user .id = user_settings .user_id

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. update user_settings set google_access_token = (select google_access_token from eltropy_user WHERE id=user_id)

Comment: No it will update only matched columns and updates NULL for unmatched columns

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do like this :

```
   insert into user_settings (google_access_token, google_refresh_token) 
   select 'google_access_token', 
          'google_refresh_token' 
   from user 
   where id in (select user_id from user_settings )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update a table with out NULLs even if you don't have matching values

```
update user_settings
set 
user_settings.google_access_token='google_access_token',
user_settings.google_refresh_token='google_refresh_token'
from user_settings
inner join user 
on user_settings.user_id=user.id
```